# Error with company-mode, using Haskell

Tags: company-mode, haskell-mode

I installed `haskell-mode`, and I follow this tutorial to install company [here](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md).
But it only ran once; now when I launch Emacs I get this error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading /home/lowley/.emacs':
File error: Cannot open load file, company
To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the --debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

on `M-x company-mode`, the company mode is activated but if I enter `putS` it proposes putStrLn only (no putStr) and the mode turns to `company-<dabbrev-code`.

Here is my emacs config file :

```
(require 'package)
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))))


(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (misterioso))))
(custom-set-faces
 )

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)

(let ((my-cabal-path (expand-file-name "~/.cabal/bin")))
  (setenv "PATH" (concat my-cabal-path ":" (getenv "PATH")))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path my-cabal-path))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.cabal/share/ghc-mod-5.4.0.0")

(autoload 'ghc-init "ghc" nil t)
(autoload 'ghc-debug "ghc" nil t)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (ghc-init)))

(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-ghc)
(custom-set-variables '(company-ghc-show-info t))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the ELPA packages activated already when the init script runs, you should call `(package-initialize)` first.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates that emacs cannot find the `company` package when it hits the `(require 'company)` in your init file. Use `M-x list-packages` to install it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I beleived but when I tried to install it emacs told me it was already installed. Do you know how to repair it, in case of a corrupted package ?

Comment: `package-install` followed by `company` produces a downloading and some compilations but there is an error : `Compiling file /home/lowley/.emacs.d/elpa/company-0.8.12/test/async-tests.el at Thu Nov 12 13:45:49 2015
async-tests.el:22:1:Error: Cannot open load file: company-tests`. I tried package-install company-tests but it seems to be not recognised.

Comment: Disregard the error about `company-tests`; it's a packaging problem. You don't need the tests to use it anyway.